# how to avoid blank space while using char field in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have two tables one is a customer table and the second is sales table.
I need to create a query to display customer name, customer_id and number of Gadgets bought (write two queries using different syntaxes of JOIN). Example : “John Barry - 111 bought 5 gadgets”.

**CUSTOMERS_JS**

```
create table CUSTOMERS_JS ( 
CUSTID smallint not null,
CUSTNAME char(50) not null,
primary key(CUSTID)
);
```

**STORE_SALES_JS**

```
create table STORE_SALES_JS ( 
SALEID smallint not null,
SALETS datetime not null,
GADGETID smallint not null,
EMPID smallint not null,
CUSTID smallint not null,
primary key(SALEID),
foreign key(GADGETID) references ELEC_items_JS(GADGETID),
foreign key(EMPID) references Store_EMPS_JS(EMPID),
foreign key(CUSTID) references CUSTOMERS_JS(CUSTID) 
);
```

I did this query

```
select concat(CUSTNAME,' - ',STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID,' bought ',count(STORE_SALES_JS.GADGETID),' gadgets') as result 
from CUSTOMERS_JS,STORE_SALES_JS
where STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID = CUSTOMERS_JS.CUSTID
group by STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID,CUSTNAME
order by STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID
```

but there is too much space between the name and the '-'. I tried to change the name field to varchar and it worked as it supposed to work but I need it to work with char(50) as well.[image: too much space]

Comment: "*I tried to change the name field to varchar and it worked as it supposed to work but I need it to work with char(50) as well.*"—except that is **the** difference between the two datatypes: `CHAR` is *fixed-width* whereas `VARCHAR` is *variable-width*.  You want variable-width behaviour, but are insisting on using a fixed-width datatype... ***WHY***???

Comment: `TRIM(CUSTNAME)`

Comment: @eggyal it was one of the requirements of my teacher

Answer (score -1, accepted):

if you must use char and not varchar but need  a trimmed  result in your select you could trim ( or rtrim or ltrim) your custname for remove the spaces

```
select concat(rtrim(CUSTNAME),' - '
  ,STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID,' bought '
  ,count(STORE_SALES_JS.GADGETID),' gadgets') as result 
from CUSTOMERS_JS,STORE_SALES_JS
where STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID = CUSTOMERS_JS.CUSTID
group by STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID,CUSTNAME
order by STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID
```

Comment: I'm getting an error while using trim, 'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: which db you are using

Comment: I'm using Microsoft sql server

Comment: Thanks for your help!, I'm sorry about the tagging I thought the issue was also in mysql as well

Comment: anyway  .. the trim function wrok in sql server to  .. so are you sure you are using sqlserver .. ?  which version?

Comment: @AntonMakov  ..well  (added rtrim)..and if my answer is right or lead  you to the right solution  please mark it as accepted

Comment: Maybe just update your answer if someone will use sql server instead of mysql he should use ltrim or rtrim instead of trim

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to scaisEdge help I managed to fix this issue while using rtrim function

```
select concat(rtrim(CUSTNAME),' - ',STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID,' bought ',count(STORE_SALES_JS.GADGETID),' gadgets') as result 
from CUSTOMERS_JS,STORE_SALES_JS
where STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID = CUSTOMERS_JS.CUSTID
group by STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID,CUSTNAME
order by STORE_SALES_JS.CUSTID
```

[image: problem solved]